# facial recognition project Exit code 132 error: does anybody know what might be the cause to this?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, face-recognition, apple-m1

Hi I have been working on a facial recognition project on my mac with an M1 processor, using the facial recognition and opencv library in python, I created a Conda environment for this project and installed my packages inside but somehow I ran into this error.

Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)

Would someone have an idea as to why this is happening? I would really appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
 import face_recognition as fr
 import numpy as np
 import cv2

 #create encoding profiles:
 face_1 = fr.load_image_file('assets/Seica.JPG')
 face_1_encoding = fr.face_encodings(face_1)[0]

 face_2 = fr.load_image_file('assets/Person photo.JPG')
 face_2_encoding = fr.face_encodings(face_2)[0]

 face_3 = fr.load_image_file('assets/Person2.JPG')
 face_3_encoding = fr.face_encodings(face_3)[0]

 known_face_encodings = [face_1_encoding,face_2_encoding,face_3_encoding]
 known_face_names = ["Seica","Ambrose","Sahil"]

 #Run Face Recognition on unknown faces
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 while True:
     ret,frame = cap.read()
     unknown = fr.load_image_file(frame)
     face_locations = fr.face_locations(frame)
     face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(frame,face_locations)

     for (top,right,bottom,left),face_encodings in zip(face_locations,face_encodings):
         matches = fr.compare_faces(known_face_encodings,face_encodings)
         name = "Unkown"
         #which one is best matched index
         face_distances = fr.face_distance(known_face_encodings,face_encodings)
         best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
         if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
         cv2.rectangle(frame,(left,top),(right,bottom),(0,255,0),3)
         cv2.putText(frame,name,(left,top-20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
         cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
         if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do all those packages actually have versions for the M1?  SIGILL is "illegal instruction".

Comment: openCV seems to be supported because I have other scripts running openCV in the same project file and they are working fine, I'm not sure if there is a specific version for M1 for face recognition but the installation process for that was fine as well and I could see the package installed

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this problem happens when you have multiple python interpreters installed, and some of them are for different architectures (x86_64 vs arm64). You need to make sure that the correct python interpreter is being used, if you installed Apple's version of OpenCV Python packages, then that probably requires an arm64 interpreter.

If you use rosetta (Apple's x86_64 emulator) then you need to use a x86_64 python interpreter, if you somehow load the arm64 python interpreter, you will get the illegal instruction error (which totally makes sense).

If you use any script that installs new python interpreters, then you need to make sure the correct interpreter for the architecture is installed (most likely arm64).

Overall I think this problem happens because the python environment setup is not made for systems that can run multiple instruction sets/architectures, pip does check the architecture of packages and the host system but seems you can run a x86_64 interpreter to load a package meant for arm64 and this produces the problem.

For reference you can check : https://opencv.org/opencv-python-for-apples-m1-chip-a-detective-story-with-a-happy-ending/

Comment: I will try to sort it out, thank you for your help!

Comment: first two paragraphs are similar, identical except for the library mentioned.